# Set "Always on Top" for a window

Tags: window-manager, desktop

How do I set a window to be "Always on Top" like in Linux (ie, even if you switch to another application the current window will not go to the background, but it will stay "on top")? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youre probably looking for the free [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) application. It is really very cool. ;)

Comment: That would work, but isn't there a built-in solution?

Comment: No, there is no built-in way for a user to keep an arbitrary window on top of the stack.

Comment: Is it for Mavericks too?

Comment: @rraallvv Two years old answer, so sry, don't know. Didn't tried it under Mavericks. Some applications has builtin this functionality, like MplayerX or VLC and such.

Comment: Note that the Afloat application pointed to by jm666 hasn't been updated in years, but there is fork updated for Yosemite: https://github.com/rinckd/afloat