# How to use "open in terminal", and "two windows side by side" on mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, window-manager

I'm a Linux user. I just bought my first Macbook but I still need some features from Linux that I think are also useful. For example:

1. Open in terminal (right click and choose menu to open the current folder path in terminal)
2. Two windows side by side (this feature from Windows.)

How can I get these features?

Comment: Normally we prefer one question per session so to be able to sort, search and find the answers individually, but since you are a newcomer we let it pass this time.

Comment: Your originally second question is already answered [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17293/set-always-on-top-for-a-window?rq=1) which is one reason why it is preferable to stick to the one question per question rule. The other key reason is that having several questions makes it difficult/impossible to "accept" one answer (see the [FAQ] for details on how the site works).

Comment: Recent  versions of MacOS can do the Two Windows side by side natively.  Hover over the maximize button of the window to get suggestions

Answer (score 4):

For the number one, just put the terminal icon in the doc then drag the desired folder to the icon and it open the path

Comment: or use this http://www.macworld.com/article/1047793/folderinterm.html

Comment: or add the Terminal icon to your Finder toolbar. This way you can drag and drop Folders/Files on there. To do this

Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal -> drag/drop next to the search bar at the top in the current Finder window

Comment: Or see [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location)

Answer (score 1):

To your question #2:

OS X does not have the Split screen feature.

How ever there are [3d party apps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) that do just that.

[image]

Comment: In addition to this comment, I recommend 'Window Magnet'. It is available in the App Store and sits nicely in your MenuBar. I can also recommend 'Cinch', even though the last time I used it it had far less options than Window Magnet...and was for free.

Comment: Or see [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5857/how-to-make-terminals-open-side-by-side?rq=1) for a lot of other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer 1: Open in terminal

You can use [DTerm](http://decimus.net/dterm) which is also work with other app like Sublime...

## Answer 2: Snap windows

You can use [spectacle](https://github.com/eczarny/spectacle)

Both of them are free.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer 2:

There is a way to split screen natively:

1. Maximize App1 window using the green button, it will be moved to a new desktop
   (e.g. desktop #2)
2. Swipe back to desktop #1
3. Press control+up, or Swipe 3-fingers up (shows all windows in desktop)
4. Drag App2 onto App1 in desktop #1